# Treatment after a queuable Job is over

Tags: lightning-aura-components, queueable-apex

When my  users click **Validate**, I enqueue a job and I have for this job to be over, to continue the treatment.

I'm doing it in three steps :

1. enqueue the job, and return its ID (1)
2. *this is where I'm not sure how to proceed*
3. do some treatment that has to be done after the first step is over (2)

I don't know how to wait for the first to be complete and be able to call the second part of the treatment ;
I've thought about some king of reccursive logic as [this example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218287/create-a-time-delay-in-apex-without-exceeding-cpu-limit) :

```
public class QueueablePoller implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
private String taskId;

public QueueablePoller(String taskToPoll) {
    taskId = taskToPoll;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
    String status = getQueryStatus(taskId);
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase('Complete')) {
        //Calling another method to get data
        retrieveDataFromDataExtensionWithFilters();
    } else {
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueablePoller(taskId));
    }
}
```

}

This is in a controller from a Lightning Component.
If you got some ideas, it should be something many devs have faced and I could use your advices !

EDIT : another option is to call the fird part by trigger on Justificatif__c, onUpdate, because the job enqueued (KYC_DocumentAnalysis()) is on Justificatif__c.
Is it better ?

(1)

```
       public static Id validerDossier(String accountId){
    // get the list of justif
    List<Justificatif__c> justifList = [SELECT Id, DocumentJouve__c, NbValidation__c,  DocumentJouve_verso__c, Nb_Envoi_Email__c 
                                        FROM Justificatif__c
                                        WHERE Client__c = :accountId
                                            AND A_Afficher_Portail__c  = TRUE
                                            AND Statut_SGEBS_Remediation__c  = 'A collecter'];

    // update des justifs pour prendre en compte le clic sur VALIDER (et incrémenter les compteurs sur Justif, et par PB sur Account.nbValidation__c aussi)
    if(!justifList.isEmpty()) {
        justifList[0].NbValidation__c++;
        update justifList[0];
    }

    Id jobID;
    for(Justificatif__c just : justifList) {


            jobID = System.enqueueJob(new KYC_DocumentAnalysis(just.DocumentJouve__c, just.Id,0,false));

        }
    }

    return jobID;
}
```

(2) : last part, after enqueued job are Complete

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean validerDossier_postAnalyse(String accountId, Id pendingJob_docAnalysisId){

    System.debug('validerDossier_postAnalyse() - début de la fonction.');

    // GET LIST OF JUSTIFS FOR THE PP
    List<Justificatif__c> justifListAfterAnalysis = [SELECT Id, Type_Source__c, Type_Source_2__c, NbValidation__c, Nb_Envoi_Email__c, Statut_Jouve__c 
                                                    FROM Justificatif__c
                                                    WHERE Client__c = :accountId
                                                        AND A_Afficher_Portail__c  = TRUE
                                                        AND Statut_SGEBS_Remediation__c  = 'A collecter'];



    // Send mails + update Justifs (incrémente Nb_Envoi_Email__c ou fill type_Source)

    // 1st step - Déterminer si l'user a des pièces envoyées et KO
    Boolean sendMailRelance=false;
    Integer nbValidations = 0;
    Integer nbMailRelance = 0;


    for(Justificatif__c just : justifListAfterAnalysis) {
        nbValidations =(Integer) Math.max(nbValidations, just.NbValidation__c); // loop sur les just pour récupérer le nombre de validations
        nbMailRelance =(Integer) Math.max(nbMailRelance, just.Nb_Envoi_Email__c); // loop sur les just pour récupérer le nombre d'emails de relance envoyés
        System.debug('\n\nListToUploadController -- justificatif : '+just+'\net son statut Jouve :'+just.Statut_Jouve__c); // TODO : Voir comment jouer ça en différé car les résultats des KYC_DocAnalysis ne sont pas encore revenus !

        if(just.Statut_Jouve__c==KYC_Constantes.KOradlad) { // TODO : c'est uniquement les cas KO qui déclenchent mail ? Vérifier cohérence.
            sendMailRelance=true;
        }
    }


    // GET INFORMATIONS for MAILING (both mailRelance or mailDeactivation)
    Account acc = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId LIMIT 1];
    String userMail = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE AccountId = :acc.Id LIMIT 1].Email;
    Contact con =[SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :acc.Id LIMIT 1];

    System.debug('\n\nListToUploadController -- nbValidations : '+nbValidations+'\nsendMailRelance ? : '+sendMailRelance);

    // 2nd step - Préparer le mail si pas encore 3 validations
    if(nbValidations<3) {
        if(sendMailRelance) {
            // màj du nombre de mails de relance envoyés (sur tous les justifs)
            nbMailRelance++;
            for(Justificatif__c just : justifListAfterAnalysis) {
                just.Nb_Envoi_Email__c = nbMailRelance;
            }

            System.debug('ListToUploadController - ValiderDossier() - ENVOYER LE MAIL DE RELANCE, nbValidation : '+nbValidations);

            // SEND MAIL RELANCE
            sendMail(acc, userMail, con, 'CDN-MissingDocuments_email_community');
            // update justifListAfterAnalysis;
        } else {
            // TODO AMA 27/02 : ici, clore l'espace du tonton
        }

    } else { // NbVal >=3 --> NEED REMPLIR TYPE DE SOURCE, CLORE DOSSIER & ENVOYER DERNIER MAIL
        // remplir le Type de Source
        for(Justificatif__c justif : justifListAfterAnalysis) {
            if(justif.Type_Source__c==null) {
                justif.Type_Source__c='Portail';
            } else {
                justif.Type_Source_2__c='Portail';
            }
        }

        // update nbMail si besoin
        /*
        if(sendMailRelance) {
            for(Justificatif__c justif : justifListAfterAnalysis) {
                justif.Nb_Envoi_Email__c++; // sur tous les justifs du coup... Ok ?
                System.debug('\nListToUploadController - validerDossier() - nb_envoi_email :'+justif.Nb_Envoi_Email__c);
            }
        }
        */

        // send last mail
        sendMail(acc, userMail, con, 'CDN-DossierClos_email_community');

        //System.debug(String.join(justifListAfterUpdate, '\nJustif modifié : '));
    }

    // update (pour incrément nb_Envoi_Email__c si cas IF, ou remplir Type_Source si cas ELSE ci dessus)
    update justifListAfterAnalysis;

    // switch case on nbValidation : on return TRUE si le user doit être désactivé
    return (nbValidations<3?false:true);

}
```

EDIT : I changed a lot of my code, really. But for the reccursive queuable, I'll put it there as it's working well now.
Thanks for your help !

```
/**
 * Created by Alexis MASSON on 28/02/2020.
 *
 * Usefull for VALIDER on portal (ListToUpload)
 * It's part of the treatment, in order for analysis to be over (and Statut_Jouve__c filled), and to allow the remaining treatment.
 */
public with sharing class Queuable_WaitKYC_DocAnalysisResults  implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private static Integer nbIterations=0;
    private List<Id> taskListIds;
    private List<Justificatif__c> justifToTreatList;


    // Constructor
    public Queuable_WaitKYC_DocAnalysisResults(List<Id> taskListIds, List<Justificatif__c> justifToTreatList) {
        this.taskListIds = taskListIds;
        this.justifToTreatList = justifToTreatList;
    }

    // reccursif until jobs are all complete
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
        List<AsyncApexJob> pendingAnalysis = [SELECT Status,NumberOfErrors
                                              FROM AsyncApexJob
                                                WHERE Id=:taskListIds AND Status!='Completed'];

        System.debug('\n\nRemaining analysis : '+pendingAnalysis.size()+'.');
        System.debug('     List of it : \n' + String.join(pendingAnalysis, '\n    Job :'));

        // If all jobs are finished, go further ; if not, reccursive loop
        if(pendingAnalysis.isEmpty()) {
            // FINISH TREATMENT
            System.debug('Treatment over after ' + nbIterations +' loop(s) !');
            ListToUploadController.validerDossier_postAnalyse(justifToTreatList);
        } else {
            nbIterations++;
            System.debug('Loop n°'+nbIterations);
            System.enqueueJob(new Queuable_WaitKYC_DocAnalysisResults(taskListIds, justifToTreatList));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the "further treatment" you're trying to do? Is it something that the user will need to do? There's a few possible solutions depending on the exact situation, so the more specific you are, the better we can assist you.

Comment: Ok then, I'll update my post with the last part of the treatment ! Basically, it consist in blocking the user (depending on a nbValidation__c criteria, >=3) and sending a mail depending on the situation (user is blocked, or not yet)

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: To be more specific, the further treatment does not involve a user's action.

Comment: OK !! I did it, it's working !
The only thing left is : is there a better way to do it ? I'm not reaching limits, but I'm queuing a job until it's complete, so it's a lot of SOQL..
I'm editing my question with my answer, it could be usefull.

Comment: I just realized what you're asking. Conceptually, you should just be able to have the last job you queue perform the task of going on to the next step. You could have that one perform a `FOR UPDATE` query to make sure all previous jobs are completely finished, though.